# Image Stiching using EmguCv 3.0

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I tried Image stitching using EmguCv 3.0. But it is showing the following errors:" cannot convert from 'Emgu.CV.Image[]' to 'Emgu.CV.IInputArray'". And my code is:

```
Image<Bgr, byte>[] src = new Image<Bgr, byte>[3];
        Image<Bgr, byte>res = new Image<Bgr, byte>(1000,750);
        src[0] = new Image<Bgr,byte>("D:/New folder/images/Fit01.jpg");
        src[1] = new Image<Bgr,byte>("D:/New folder/images/Fit02.jpg");
        src[2] = new Image<Bgr,byte>("D:/New folder/images/Fit03.jpg");

        Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false);
        stitcher.Stitch(src,res);//here showing error
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging at last I managed to get the answer.This is different from earlier version of EmguCv 3.0 which receives only one argument for stitching.Here is the code

```
            Mat i1 = new Mat("D:/New folder/images/Fit01.jpg", LoadImageType.Color);
            Mat i2 = new Mat("D:/New folder/images/Fit02.jpg", LoadImageType.Color);
            Mat i3 = new Mat("D:/New folder/images/Fit02.jpg", LoadImageType.Color);
            using (VectorOfMat vmsrc = new VectorOfMat(i1, i2, i3))
            {
                Image<Bgr, byte> res = new Image<Bgr, byte>(1000, 750);
                Mat result = new Mat();
                Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false);
                stitcher.Stitch(vmsrc, result);
                ImageViewer.Show(result);
            }
```